# Como verificar registros vazios no Core Data?

Tags: ios, web-service, objective-c, core-data

Estou elaborando um modo de saber se os dados foram baixados e registrados corretamente no Core Data.
 Devido a má qualidade das conexões 3G e a possibilidades de falha, gostaria de saber se há um modo de consultar o core data e ver se há como retornar os registros vazios em uma array.

A idéia inicial que tive é pegar os registros nas entidades e fazer uma varredura buscando por campos com valores NULL. E depois criar um request para preencher os dados corretamente.

Mas gostaria de saber se o Core Data tem um método ou função que providencie isso, retornando um array com os registros com falhas.

Entidade Exemplo com campos preenchidos com falha :

```
 ID | NOME  | VALOR | IMAGEM 
-------------------------------
  0 | arroz | NULL  | skms.png
-------------------------------
  1 | feijao| NULL  | ksle.png
-------------------------------
  2 | carne | 5,00  | NULL
-------------------------------
  3 | uva   | 6,00  | NULL
-------------------------------
  4 | pera  | 7,00  | lskx.png
-------------------------------
  5 | NULL  | NULL  | NULL
-------------------------------



// Codigo usado para Download
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *operationManager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    operationManager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    [operationManager.requestSerializer setValue:urlGlobalToken forHTTPHeaderField:urlGlobalHttpHeader];

    [operationManager GET:url parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        NSMutableArray* arrayDataReceived =  [responseObject objectForKey:@"data"];

        cleanArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        arrayURLImagens = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for ( NSMutableDictionary* valuesDict in arrayDataReceived) {

        // Este modelo é somente para exemplo.
        // This model is only for example.

        NSMutableDictionary* cleanDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

        [cleanDict setObject: [valuesDict objectForKey:@"id"]         forKey:@"id"];
        [cleanDict setObject: [valuesDict objectForKey:@"nome"]       forKey:@"nome"];
        [cleanDict setObject: [valuesDict objectForKey:@"data"]       forKey:@"data"];
        [cleanDict setObject: [valuesDict objectForKey:@"descricao"]  forKey:@"descricao"];
        [cleanDict setObject: [valuesDict objectForKey:@"updated_at"] forKey:@"updateat"];

        // Imagens para update
        [cleanDict setObject: [valuesDict objectForKey:@"imagem"]forKey:@"urlimagem"];
    // Armazena os dicionarios em um Array
    [cleanArray addObject:cleanDict];
}  
    _dadosBrutosRecebidos = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [_dadosBrutosRecebidos setObject:arrayURLImagens forKey:@"urlimagem"];
    [_dadosBrutosRecebidos setObject:cleanArray forKey:@"strings"];

    [self.delegate performSelector:@selector(downloadDadosEventosCompleto)];

     app.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    app.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    NSLog(@"failure. Error:%@. URL ERRO: %@",error, url);
  }];
}
```

Comment: Você pode verificar antes de salvá-los. Na verdade antes ainda de transformá-los em `NSManagedObject`

Comment: Sim estava pensando nessa alternativa, pensei em chamar o método de verificação no bloco executado no momento de falha no AFNetworking.

Comment: É muito mais fácil você verificar antes de atribuir e salvar do que você atribuir, salvar, depois verificar, e atualizar informações incorretas ou faltantes. Isso ainda impede de ocorrer algum crash (dependendo de como você vai utilizar os dados depois)

Comment: Outra coisa, eu acho meio improvável que te retorne dados incompletos, normalmente, mesmo em conexões péssimas o que acontece é demorar para concluir o retorno e se por um acaso houver perdas, o mesmo lança falha. Se algum dado estiver retornando com informações faltantes há grande chance de ser nas informações que estão retornando já de  dentro do web service ou até mesmo no converter estas informações.

Comment: Eu fiz testes de timeout e notei que mesmo o Json venha com falha o app consegue captar alguns dados e registrar no coredata normalmente, mas nem todos os itens são preenchidos normalmente (os que falharam). Por isso que acho mais lógico verificar a consistência no banco do que no momento que eles estão vindo.

Comment: poderia postar seu código? Normalmente quando utilizo requisições eu espero receber todos os dados para assim converter em objetos para salvá-los. Se puder postar seu código ficará mais fácil de auxiliá-lo

Comment: Meu codigo é uma implementação básica do AFNetworking. Vou postar para vc's verem...

Comment: A requisição de imagem é feita separada, e como se trata de uma arquivo longo ele pode não ser totalmente baixado, por diversos erros. Então a coluna NOMEIMAGEM no CoreData ficaria em branco. Por isso que a verificação deveria ser no Core Data e não no momento que ainda estou pegando a URL da imagem.

 Estou fazendo opreechimento do core data em 2 momentos distintos. Primeiro os dados e depois somente imagens. Salvo a imagem em disco e coloco o nome dela no Core Data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode instruir o CoreData a retornar o objeto que possuem as propriedades "nil".

Assumindo a entidade de seu exemplo a seguinte requisição retornará todas a entidades que possuem uma das colunas (nome, valor, imagem) como `nil` :

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = <Pega o contexto do seu CoreData aqui>;
NSEntityDescription *exemploEntityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Exemplo" inManagedObjectContext:contexto];
NSPredicate *dadosIncompletoPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(name == nil) OR (valor == nil) OR (imagem == nil)"];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
request.entity = exemploEntityDescription;
request.predicate = dadosIncompletoPreditate;

NSArray *entidatesComCamposNulos = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
```

Então é só checar se o array é vazio e diferente de `nil` e então fazer o que você precisa para garantir a consistência dos seus dados.

Além disto recomendo fortemente que você não coloque uma "coluna" com o nome "ID" no seu CoreData, `id` é palavra reservada da linguagem e pode levar a problemas no futuro.

Comment: Vlw! Pensei que seria usando algum metodo especifico!